# Python3 how to try multiple functions to find and assign value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

Currently my code looks like that:

```
img = find_image_in_feed(feed)
if img:
    e.image = img
if not e.image:
    img = find_image_on_site(site)
    if img:
        e.image = img
```

It works but it looks confusing and hard to expand. In future there may be multiple more find_image(...) functions. Is there some "design pattern" that I should use in situation like that.
My second idea  also don't looks clean for me because of assigning and checking value at the same time.

```
if img = find_image_in_feed(feed):
    e.image = img
elif img = find_image_on_site(site):
    e.image = img
```

I want my code to be as easy to read as possible, and I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `e.image = img = find_image_in_feed(feed) or find_image_on_site(site)`. If you don't need `img` anywhere down in your code, just throw it away.

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet isn't valid Python: You can't do C-style assignments  inside an `if` test because Python assignment statements aren't expressions so they don't create a testable value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `or` which works like a [`null coalescing operator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator):

```
e.image = find_image_in_feed(feed) or find_image_on_site(site)
```

Above, `e.image` is set to `find_image_in_feed(feed)` if it returns something that evaluates to true, otherwise it fall backs on the return value of `find_image_on_site(site)`.

```
>>> value = 5 or 6
>>> print(value)
5
>>> value = [] or [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(value)
[1, 2, 3]
```

In Python, `or` is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates `find_image_on_site(site)` if `find_image_in_feed(feed)` is false.

--

If you don't `e.image` being set to `None` when both calls return `None`:

```
e.image = find_image_in_feed(feed) or find_image_on_site(site) or e.image
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential ways of simplifying your code without sacrificing readability.

A: By setting the e.image once.

```
img = find_image_in_feed(feed)
if not img:
    img = find_image_on_site(site)
e.image = img
```

B: Or leveraging python ternary operators

```
img = find_image_in_feed(feed)
e.image = img if img else find_image_on_site(site)
```

[python ternary operators](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html)

Thanks,

-Abe.